# How to change html element after text has been edited

Tags: javascript, html, events, listener

I have this code that should change the contents of a table position when you change the contents of ***nameDiv*** which is  `var nameDiv = document.createElement('div');` (`nameDiv.contentEditable = "true";`) and it has some text

```
 nameDiv.onclick = event => {
            allSectionsArray[sectionNumber][2] = event.value;
 }
```

What happens here is basically: it updates the second I click on the div and not after some text is entered.

What I want is: to save changes after entering the text. Is there any substitute of `onclick` or any other method that I can achieve this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp I guess that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `contenteditable`, you can use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event:

> The input event fires when the value of an input element has been changed.

The `change` event isn't supported for `contenteditable`, but you can use the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event instead which

> fires when an element has lost focus

```js
const example = document.querySelector("#example");

example.addEventListener("blur", ()=>{
  console.log(`Value is: ${example.textContent}`);
});
```

```css
#example {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" contenteditable></div>
```

---

You can also browse the full list of events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: Specifically, what he means is that when he finishes typing, he will update it, but the input event is not suitable because it is triggered as soon as the key is clicked, in which case the onChange event is more suitable.

Comment: Hi @Mkoes, the `change` event isn't supported for `contenteditable`. If OP wants to detect when the user has _finished_ typing (this isn't that clear in the question imo), then I think the best approach would be to use the `blur` event instead

Comment: Exactly what I mean

Comment: @ChrisCosta I've updated my answer, hopefully you can use the `blur` event to update when the user clicks away from the `contenteditable` area

Comment: Do I need any kind of library? Cause it's not workink if i replace `onclick` with `blur`

Comment: @ChrisCosta No library needed, this is pure JS. I've added an example using the `blur` event

Answer (score 1):

Find below a sample how different events work with `contenteditable` elements.
You will probably need `blur` event handler to get the value when user is done typing.

```js
const code = document.querySelector('pre');
const object = {
  valueOnclick: '',
  valueOninput: '',
  valueOnblur: ''
};

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('input', e => {
  object.valueOninput = e.target.textContent;
  code.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
});

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', e => {
  object.valueOnclick = e.target.textContent;
  code.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
});

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('blur', e => {
  object.valueOnblur = e.target.textContent;
  code.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Some content</div>
<pre></pre>
```